# What is the general stance on "jump headlines"?

Tags: print-design, text, page-layout

This is more of a design opinion question, and this might be the wrong place to ask this, but I digress.

I work on a weekly newspaper that up until now has used "jump headlines", that's to say there's a second headline where the article picks up on a different page.

Looking around at other publications, especially the big ones, I've noticed that very few newspapers do this so I'm just looking for some opinions here. Are jump headlines useful in newspaper layout or do they just take up space and act redundantly?

To clarify, I'm not asking for opinions on completely removing jumps, but rather the reasons to have/not have a full blown 40pt. headline for a jump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have *something* to indicate what story you're reading. Otherwise this story just starts in the middle of a thought and you have no idea what it's connected to.

If space is a problem, use one or two words and a much smaller size. So if the main article head is "Mayor Burgermeister Cancels Christmas After Record Heat Wave," the jump head might just be "Christmas."

Or if you're really desperate for space, the lead out line under the last line of copy (written in 8 pt type) could run "see CHRISTMAS on page 6," and then the lead in line (also 8 pt) would say "CHRISTMAS from page 1."

My local paper uses the first option (a one- or two-word jump head in deck size) with "from page 1" beneath it.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the opinion! I think the general consensus on our paper is that we're trying to fill space, but I feel like we could fill that space with visuals instead of text. The purpose of my question was not to indicate that jumps should be completely eliminated, just that I'm not sure if we need a whole headline for a jump from.